# Coloring for arithmetic progressions with 2-power difference restricted to a set of numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, hypergraph, colorings

For $D \subset \mathbb N$, let $\mathbb A_D$ be the set of all arithmetic progressions with difference in $D$ (and of finite length).
Let $\mathbb A_D$ be $m$-good if for every $S \subset \mathbb N$, there is a partition $S_1 \cup S_2 = S$ such that if a sequence $A \in \mathbb A_D$ has $|S \cap A| \ge m$, then $S_1 \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and $S_2 \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

> If $D = \{2^i \mid i \in \mathbb N\}$, then is there an $m$ such that $\mathbb A_D$ is $m$-good?

Remark. I've originally posed this question two years ago as a bridge between polychromatic colorings, studied a lot for [geometric hypergraphs](https://coge.elte.hu/cogezoo.html), and combinatorial number theory, like van der Waerden's theorem. Some students worked on it, a part of them wrote up some related results [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.12154), where you can also find more explanation of the connection.

Comment: For those who are interested in small counterexamples for specific $m$, for $m=3$ a counter-example requires $|S| \ge 10$; one such is $S = \{ 0, 64, 160, 264, 388, 512, 514, 641, 656, 768 \}$. (The counterexample $S = \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$ for $m=2$ is easy, but perhaps worth mentioning anyway).

Comment: For a similar counterexample, you can also see Figure 1 on the top-left of page 6 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.0169.pdf - I leave it as homework to convert the planar point set to integers, or you can find the connection in the write-up linked to above.

Comment: I was wondering if there is anything known for the following:
Does there exist $m$ such that, given any finite point set in the plane, we can colour it in two colours such that no axis-parallel rectangle containing at least $m$ points is monochromatic?

Comment: @1001 It is known that there is no such $m$, see X. Chen, J. Pach, M. Szegedy, G. Tardos, Delaunay graphs of point sets in the plane with respect to axis-parallel rectangles, Random Struct. Algorithms, 34:11-23, 2009 at https://math.nyu.edu/~pach/publications/rectangle120406.pdf. You can find these things on the webpage https://coge.elte.hu/cogezoo.html linked to in the question, just type rectangle in the search box, and then click on the appropriate box to see the references.

Comment: what happens if you just consider intervals (sets of the form $S = \{1,\dots,N\}$)? is it obvious that $m$ must be finite for these?

Comment: @Zach RRBRRBRRB... coloring mod 3 shows that $m\le 3$ in this case.